# How to show image from Oracle database in an ASP.NET MVC view?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC application. In one of my views, I need to display an image of the logged in person. I am doing following things but the image is not displayed on the view.

In my view I have this markup:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 img-thumbnail" id="userimage">
    </div>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
        var url = "@Session("baseurl")/Navigation/ShowImage";
        $('#userimage').load(url);
}
</script>
```

In my controller, I have this code:

```
Function ShowImage(DashBoard As DashBoard) As ActionResult
            Dim str As String
            Dim cmd As OracleCommand
            Dim dr As OracleDataReader
            Dim UserImage As Byte()

            Globals.OpenDBConnection()
            str = "Select EMP_IMAGE from EMP_MASTER,LOGIN_USER WHERE USER_EMP_CODE=EMP_CODE AND USER_ID='" + Session("UserId") + "'"
            cmd = New OracleCommand(str, Globals.oraConnection)
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

            If dr.Read Then
                DashBoard.UserImage = dr(0)
                'UserImage = dr(0)
            End If

            dr.Close()
            Globals.CloseDBConnection()

            Return PartialView("ShowImage", DashBoard)
            'Return File(UserImage, "image/TIFF")

        End Function
```

In my partial view `ShowImage`, I have this markup and code:

```
@ModelType SdesWeb.Controls_MVC.Models.DashBoard

@code
    Dim img As String = Convert.ToBase64String(Model.UserImage)
    Dim imgsrc As String = String.Format("data:image/jpg;base64,{0}", img)
End Code

<div class="col-md-4 img-thumbnail">
    <!--<img src="data:image;base64,System.Convert.ToBase64String(@Model.UserImage)" width="80" height="80" />-->
    <img src="@imgsrc" />
</div>
```

I don't know where my mistake is. Kindly help me solve the issue.

Comment: What have you done to debug this? Have you verified that the action is being called (via your browser's dev tools)?

Comment: yes action is being called and value also coming in the variable,But i want to mention here the field type for image in database is LONG RAW.

Comment: Hi, can anybody help me to solve the issue?